# How to store class name for repeatedly clicked tags in a list using java-script and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, click

I'm creating a memory game using html, css and javascript whereby a user is asked to match a set of cards with each other. I'm currently stuck on extracting the cards class names, which represent card type, when the user clicks on them and store it in a list. I managed to store only one class name when the user clicks on a card, but when I tried it for next card and store class name in a list I failed. I tried using both for and while loops. here is my code:

HTML part for cards:

```
<li class="card">
  <i class="car"></i>
</li>
<li class="card">
  <i class="cat"></i>
</li>
<li class="card">
  <i class="car"></i>
</li>
<li class="card">
  <i class="cat"></i>
</li>
```

JavaScript part:

```
for (var i=0, i<2, i++) {
  $(".card").click(function() {
    clickedList[i] = $(this).children().attr("class");
  });
}
```

Please note that I have clickedList as a global array.

What I really want to do as below:

1. click a card and store its class name in clickedList[0]
2. click another card and store its class name in clickedList[1]
3. compare clickedList[0] and clickedList[1] if they match or not

Comment: why click inside `for loop`? how's your for loop going to trigger ?

Comment: Isn't the for loop in this case are triggered automatically? I mean loops don't need a trigger they are just run with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the loop and use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to index the elements

```js
var clickedList={}

var $cards = $(".card").click(function() {
    var cardIndex = $cards.index(this)
    clickedList[cardIndex] = $(this).children().attr("class");
    console.log(clickedList)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="card">
  <i class="car">car</i>
</li>
<li class="card">
  <i class="cat">cat</i>
</li>
<li class="card">
  <i class="car">car</i>
</li>
<li class="card">
  <i class="cat">cat</i>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, this made me closer to my goal but didn't solve exactly my problem. What I really want to do as below:

1 click a card and store its class name in clickedList[0]
2 click another card and store its class name in clickedList[1]
3 compare clickedList[0] and clickedList[1] if they match or not